# Exclude G/L with UserResponse in Webi report

Tags: business-objects, webi

I am using Business Objects WEBi to build a new report.

In a cell I want to show the UserResponse to the G/Ls that have been excluded in a list, but when I use the formula `=UserResponse["G/Ls to Exclude:"]` I get a blank cell

[image]

How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the string has any blank spaces trailing at the back or front of the string . This may sometime does not bring the value available in the user response.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the "G/Ls to Exclude:" is holding the exact string what you have give in the prompt display.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try without double quotes?

```
=UserResponse[G/Ls to Exclude:]
```